# Bivariate normal exercise - check my answer please

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Similar to the question I asked before, with one subtle difference.

If $X \sim N(20,2^2)$ and $Y \sim N(10,1)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are correlated with $\rho = 0.5$

then find:

$a)$ the covariance between  $X$ and $Y$

$b)$ The distribution of the vector $(X,Y)$

$c)$ **give the distribution** of $U = 2X-3Y$ and specify the mean and variance

For
$a) $ $\rho = COV(X,Y)/ \sqrt{VAR(X)VAR(Y)} $ so $COV(X,Y) = 1$

for

$b)$

$(X,Y) \sim N(\mu, \Sigma) 
= \sim N[ \begin{pmatrix} 20 \\ 10 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0.5 \\ 0.5 & 1 \end{pmatrix}]$

for the next part I am not entirely sure:

$c)$

Since expectation is a linear operator: $E(U) = E(2X) + E(-3Y) = 2E(X) - 3E(Y) = 2(20) - 3(10) = 10$

Now for Variance I am a little unsure,

$VAR(2X-3Y) = VAR(2X) + 2COV(2X,-3Y) + VAR(3Y)$

$= 4VAR(X) - 12COV(X,Y) + VAR(3Y)$

$= 4(4) - 12 + 9(1) = 13$

And the distribution of $2X-3Y$ is $U \sim N(10,13)$

Are my solutions correct?